# SQL: Order by substring of mixed letters and numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How might I select the following data in an existing table and order by a mix of letters and numbers.  Here is the sample...

```
A-1
A-10
A-2
A-3
A-4
A-5
A-6
A-7
A-8
A-9
A-3a
A-3b
A-3c
B-1
B-10
B-11
B-12
B-12a
B-12b
B-13
B-2
B-3
B-4
B-5
B-6
B-7
B-8
B-9
```

Comment: what should the result look like?what have you tried?

Comment: @vkp - I think they're providing what the output should look like where they're sorting letters first and then numbers into a list like this.  However without any reference to previous work or how this person's data is stored in a table or tables there's no way to answer this without taking a shot in the dark. It would be pretty easy to make a query if they can provide that information though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hirarchical sorting in sql server when child id contains '.'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732163/hirarchical-sorting-in-sql-server-when-child-id-contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I place this as a new answer, as it is not really an answer but rather a comparison of different approaches:

#### The conclusio:

- all approaches scale fairly linear, except XML
- XML is fastest with small row count but gets worse with high row count

#### Create a test scenario

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ID INT IDENTITY,sortColumn VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
 ('A-1')
,('A-10')
,('A-2')
,('A-3')
,('A-4')
,('A-5')
,('A-6')
,('A-7')
,('A-8')
,('A-9')
,('A-3a')
,('A-3b')
,('A-3c')
,('B-1')
,('B-10')
,('B-11')
,('B-12')
,('B-12a')
,('B-12b')
,('B-13')
,('B-2')
,('B-3')
,('B-4')
,('B-5')
,('B-6')
,('B-7')
,('B-8')
,('A-8a')
,('B-8')
,('B-9'); --30 rows
GO 1000  -- x 1.000 = 30.000 rows
```

#### Matt's approach (cleaned to the necessary)

- 46 seconds on 3 mio rows
- 4.5 seconds on 300.000 rows
- 1.3 seconds on 30.000 rows
- 0.7 seconds on 3.000 rows

The code

```
SELECT ID,sortColumn
FROM
    #tbl
ORDER BY
LEFT(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) -1)
,CAST((CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,3)
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,2)
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,1)
    ELSE NULL
END) AS INT)
,RIGHT(sortColumn,
    LEN(sortColumn) - 
    LEN(LEFT(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) -1)) 
    - LEN(CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,3)
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,2)
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(sortColumn,CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) + 1,1)
            ELSE NULL
    END)
    - 1 --the '-'
),ID;
```

#### Stepwise calculation in `CROSS APPLY`s, sorting on calculated columns

- 44 seconds on 3 mio rows
- 4.4 seconds on 300.000 rows
- 0.9 seconds on 30.000 rows
- 0.3 seconds on 3.000 rows

The code

```
SELECT ID,sortColumn
FROM #tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) AS posMinus) AS pos
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(sortColumn,1,posMinus-1) AS part1
                  ,SUBSTRING(sortColumn,posMinus+1,1000) AS part2
            ) AS parts
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ISNUMERIC(part2) AS p2isnum) AS checknum
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN p2isnum=1 THEN '' ELSE RIGHT(part2,1) END AS part3
                  ,CASE WHEN p2isnum=1 THEN part2 ELSE SUBSTRING(part2,1,LEN(part2)-1) END AS part2New
           ) AS partsNew
ORDER BY part1,part2new,part3,ID;
```

#### Stepwise calculation in `CROSS APPLY`s, sorting on concatenated padded string

- 42 seconds on 3 mio rows
- 4.2 seconds on 300.000 rows
- 0.7 seconds on 30.000 rows
- 0.4 seconds on 3.000 rows

The code

```
SELECT ID,sortColumn
FROM #tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn) AS posMinus) AS pos
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(sortColumn,1,posMinus-1) AS part1
                  ,SUBSTRING(sortColumn,posMinus+1,1000) AS part2
            ) AS parts
ORDER BY RIGHT('.....' + part1,5) + RIGHT('.....' + part2,5 - ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(part2,1)))
        ,ID;
```

#### Splitting with XML, sorting on concatenated padded string

- 67 seconds on 3 mio rows
- 6.2 seconds on 300.000 rows
- 0.7 seconds on 30.000 rows
- 0.3 seconds on 3.000 rows

The code

```
SELECT ID,sortColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(sortColumn,'-','</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML) AS SortColumnSplitted
          ,*
    FROM #tbl
) AS tbl
ORDER BY RIGHT('.....' + SortColumnSplitted.value('r[1]','varchar(max)'),5) + RIGHT('.....' + SortColumnSplitted.value('r[2]','varchar(max)'),5 - ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(SortColumnSplitted.value('r[2]','varchar(max)'),1)))
        ,ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the XML solution and it sorted my table perfectly.  Speed was not an issue as it was only 1,000+ rows and I only need to run the script occasionally to clean up the data.

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful solution is to create an [SQL CLR function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10840893/5931028). That's a bit tough, though.

Another approach is writing an insert/update trigger that splits the value in the mixed column with TSQL and stores the three parts (character, number, character) in specific helper columns (that you can use to sort).
Based on your examples, you can experiment with the splitting along the lines of this code:

```
declare @value nvarchar(10) = 'B-12b';

-- first part
select substring(@value, 1, 1)

-- second part
select case when isnumeric(right(@value, 1)) = 1
    then substring(@value, 3, len(@value) - 2)
    else substring(@value, 3, len(@value) - 3)
    end

-- third part
select case when isnumeric(right(@value, 1)) = 1
    then '_'
    else right(@value, 1)
    end
```

Comment: Your code assumes there's never something like "A1" before the "-"  as you deal with given character positions. This might be correct. The chain of calculations, which is rather useless in this form (dealing only with one variable) might be done in a chain of `CROSS APPLY`s, which was a pretty good approach actually...

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I just added another answer with a comparison of different approaches. There I tried the chain of `CROSS APPLY`s (but not with fix positions but with `CHARINDEX('-',sortColumn)`) and found this best. Might be interesting...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with thomas, but I also have a lot of the .Net Regex and String functions exposed via CLR.  Other techniques we use a little are user defined functions that recursively go character by character to strip out non desired characters (e.g. no alpha when looking for a number, no number when looking for alpha).  But in the particular case you presented if you know the format will be pretty standard you can use a combination of ISNUMERIC, SUBSTRINGS, etc. to reach your goal pretty easily.  For example.  If you know it is always:
Alpha + "-" + Numeric (1-3 digits) + alpha
you could do the following and it will sort The alpha as alpha, numeric as numeric, and alpha as alpha.

```
DECLARE @Values AS TABLE (Value VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Values (Value)
    VALUES ('A-1')
    ,('A-10')
    ,('A-2')
    ,('A-3')
    ,('A-4')
    ,('A-5')
    ,('A-6')
    ,('A-7')
    ,('A-8')
    ,('A-9')
    ,('A-3a')
    ,('A-3b')
    ,('A-3c')
    ,('B-1')
    ,('B-10')
    ,('B-11')
    ,('B-12')
    ,('B-12a')
    ,('B-12b')
    ,('B-13')
    ,('B-2')
    ,('B-3')
    ,('B-4')
    ,('B-5')
    ,('B-6')
    ,('B-7')
    ,('B-8')
    ,('B-9')

SELECT
    *
    ,FirstAlphaSection = LEFT(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) -1)
    ,SecondNumericSection = CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)
       ELSE NULL
    END
    ,ThirdAlphaSection =
       RIGHT(Value,
          LEN(Value) - 
          LEN(LEFT(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) -1)) 
          - LEN(CASE
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)
                WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)
                ELSE NULL
          END)
          - 1 --the '-'
       )
FROM
    @Values
ORDER BY
    LEFT(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) -1)
    ,CAST((CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)
       ELSE NULL
    END) AS INT)
    ,RIGHT(Value,
       LEN(Value) - 
       LEN(LEFT(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) -1)) 
       - LEN(CASE
             WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,3)
             WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,2)
             WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)) = 1 THEN SUBSTRING(Value,CHARINDEX('-',Value) + 1,1)
             ELSE NULL
       END)
       - 1 --the '-'
    )
```

Comment: This is quite complicated... You might reduce the code if you put the SELECT into a CTE and use the named columns in your `ORDER BY`. You would reach the same by calling your `SELECT` as a sub-select.

Comment: Shnugo, As far as I read the question he doesn't really need the columns I simply included so he/she would understand how the sorting would happen.  So really only need the code in one place the order by statement and no need for adding CTE at that point unless you like that to organize your code differently.  Becareful though if the queries become much more complex CTE may not be best for execution plan.  And for subselect I see no reason for that here.  As far as SELECT as sub-select by all means post a simplified answer to the question I am game to learn more every day.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I just posted one more answer with a comparison of different approaches. Might be interesting...

Comment: @Shnugo intersting post!  I like the bench marking for the answers seems most are pretty much a wash except XML.  I would be curious how an CLR table valued function (not scalar!) fairs at the task, Especially because that would enable regex and a more robust pattern.  Perhaps I will try it at some point and post back here.